# set three button in a line (Horizontally) android studio with LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, button, android-linearlayout

I am working an android app for learning.
and facing some problem.
Can't set a button center of two.
I already set two button with this
Now I need another button in the center of this two
and The view will be as like as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZRqu.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:background="#dde5ad" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:background="#dde5ad" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need exactly center of this two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `layout_weight` & `layout_gravity` for this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            android:text="Set" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            android:text="Set" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            android:text="No" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @TamalDev glad that this helps you, Can you please up vote this answer?  So others can also find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**use layout_weight**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        android:text="Set" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_neutral_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="your text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="No" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of unnecessary linear layouts. If you only need to add three buttons in a row, you can do it with only on horizontal `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        />

    <!-- this is your new Button -->
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No"
        android:background="#dde5ad"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also note that nesting lienar layout may affect your performance. If you need to do complex layout, try with [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Hope it helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the *android:layout_weight="1"* for each button, each of them takes 1/3 of the available width so that they are evenly spaced horizontally. See the layouts below, you have 2 options to get similar results, one uses the *gravity* while the other *layout_weight*. The final result is similar but the option with *layout_weight="1"* is preferable:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />


        <Button
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

***Or you have this second option:***

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Set"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />


        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="No"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:background="#dde5ad"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is a concept of LayoutWeights while using LinearLayout, as it is a broad topic I suggest you go through the official documentation [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#dde5ad"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#dde5ad"
    android:text="Set" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="#000" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#dde5ad"
    android:text="No" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="#000" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#dde5ad"
    android:text="No" />
```

Comment: I think he added `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.